# Can't call parent function inside __call() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance

This is my code below.

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public function __call($method, $parameters = null) {
        if($method == 'create'){
            return parent::create($parameters[0]);
            if(!$created) {
                throw new \App\Exceptions\EloquentException;
            }else{
                return $created;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call update function of MyModel class instance from postman, something bad happens. It gets stuck and I have to restart my computer each time. So what may the problem be?

Comment: can you show whole code of your model

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this. What is the reason you've implemented this/what it is meant to achieve over the default behaviour?

Comment: the only scenario you have is `if($method == 'create'){` so you can call `update` function but it will do nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to assume you're simply trying to have a common handler for the create function, that is, to throw an `EloquentException` in case the create returns a `null` or `false`.

If that's the case, you have an excess `return` statement on line above the `if` statement, and you should assign the return value of the parent's create method to a variable `$created` that you use later. You may also remove the `else` part as code below `throw` is never going to be executed if the exception is thrown.

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public function __call($method, $parameters = null)
    {
        if ($method == 'create') {
            $create = parent::create($parameters[0]);
            if (!$created) {
                throw new \App\Exceptions\EloquentException;
            }
            return $created;
        }
    }
}
```

It would be better if you could elaborate on the task you're trying to achieve, I feel you're doing it the wrong way.